# Cannot install Heroku on Win7, getting error "/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, ruby, facebook, heroku

I am trying to install Heroku for a facebook app. When i try to run **$ heroku login** as it says here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#heroku_account_and_tools_setup I get the following error:

```
/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

I don't even want to use ruby, I need php. I don't have php/ruby installed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you could do

1. Download heroku toolbet
2. Download TortoiseGit
3. Setup SSH keys, you can use putty agent
4. Git Clone the new heroku app you made using tortoisegit
5. Make changes on your folder
6. Commit your changes
7. Push the changes
8. Test the app via adding it on a facebook page

Its not as easy as it looks but it has to be done this way unless you have an https server.

There are documentations there that could help you out.

Good luck :)

Comment: I have installed heroku toolbelt, installed tortoisegit 1.7.6, generated a SSH-2 key with puttygen. I don't know how to do step 4 and further.

Comment: Have you used Git before?
go to https://api.heroku.com/myapps to see the list of apps you have, then click on your app there and find your Git Repo. put that git@heroku.com:*.git into tortoisegit to clone this into your local folder.